# Get windows/system folder location in Python

Tags: python, windows, path, system

How would I go about getting the Windows/System folder paths in python?  I need to be able to read from an INI that gets written to the Windows directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the environment variable `%WINDIR%`.

```
import os
winpath = os.environ['WINDIR'] + "\\System\\"
inifile = open(winpath + filename)
```

Comment: this is not true for 64bit Windows ther it is os.environ['WINDIR'] + "\\SYSWOW64\\"

Comment: @maxbit89 True. But note that this depends on the bitness of the application as well. A 64-bit application on a 64-bit OS reads from the `Windir\System` directory, while a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS needs to use the wow64-directory, as you point out.

Comment: This also happens in the registry, btw, if you have to interact with that.